# Alchemy provider API provider does not support signing

Tags: ethers.js, dapps, web3-providers, alchemy

I am using AlchemyProvider with ether.js to deploy a smart contract using frontend data
But I am not able to sign the provider i.e AlchemyProvider.

Code

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.AlchemyProvider("maticmum","apikey");
const signer = provider.getSigner()
```

Error

```
Error: API provider does not support signing (operation="getSigner", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=providers/5.7.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AlchemyProvider extends UrlJsonRpcProvider
```

and UrlJsonRpcProvider implements getSigner as follows:

```
getSigner(address?: string): JsonRpcSigner {
    return logger.throwError(
        "API provider does not support signing",
        Logger.errors.UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION,
        { operation: "getSigner" }
    );
}
```

If you need a signer for deployment - create wallet and pass the alchemy provider to it:

```
const signer = new ethers.Wallet("PRIVATE_KEY", ALCHEMY_PROVIDER)
```

Comment: Thanks @Konsantin its working now.